# How to add div element on button click in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Javascript and HTML code as shown below.
The idea is to click on the PLUS (+) button and generate a new row with the HTML present in **rowAdd()** function.

**HTML code** has 3 input boxes.

```js
     function rowAdd(event) {
       document.getElementById('house-senate-committee').insertAdjacentHTML('aftereend', newRow());  <!-- Line B -->
     }        
     function newRow() {
      return  `<div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;">
         <input type="text" name="code[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="">
         <input type="text" name="en_desc[]" value="">
         <input type="text" name="fr_desc[]" style="margin-left:10px;" value="">
        </div>`;
     }
```

```html
    <!-- Add New Row Button START -->
    <div class="plus-minus-button" style="text-align:center;">    
     <button type="button" onclick="rowAdd()">+</button>   <!-- Line A -->
    </div>
    <!-- Add New Row Button END -->
    
    <div id"house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;"> <!-- Big div START -->
         <!-- Code START -->  
           <input type="text" name="code[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="">
     <!-- Code END -->
    
         <!-- EN Desc START -->  
            <input type="text" name="en_desc[]" value="">
         <!-- EN Desc END -->
    
         <!-- FR Desc START -->  
           <input type="text" name="fr_desc[]" style="margin-left:10px;" value="">
         <!-- FR Desc END -->
    </div> <!-- Big DIV END -->
```

The above Javascript code shows content but its not adding div element row by row like this:

```
<div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;">
</div>

<div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;">
</div>

<div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;">
</div>

<div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center;margin-top:15px;">
</div>
```

Comment: May you convert your code into a runnable snippet? Try only showing us the rendered HTML rather than the PHP.

Comment: IDs have to be unique in a HTML document, switch to class or make them unique, maybe by adding a count `id="house-senate-committee-01"`

Comment: @nito Agree, I do believe ids have to be unique in the DOM.I tried with **document.getElementsByClassName('test')** but for some reasons, it was throwing an error.

Comment: `getElementById ` returns 1 element, `getElementsByClassName ` returns all 4

Answer (score 1):

Switch to `getElementsByClassName` and grab the first element `[0]`, and change the spot to insert to `beforebegin` or `afterend`.

And to make things work, you have to invoke `rowAdd()` somehow, on click or just by calling it at some place in the code as I did it.

```js
    function rowAdd() {
      document.getElementsByClassName('house-senate-committee')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', newRow());
    }          
    function newRow() {
  return  `<div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;border:1px solid">News div
     <input type="text" name="code[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="">
     <input type="text" name="en_desc[]" value="">
     <input type="text" name="fr_desc[]" style="margin-left:10px;" value="">
    </div>`;;
    }
```

```html
<div class="plus-minus-button" style="text-align:center;">    
    <button type="button" onclick="rowAdd()">+</button> 
</div>
<div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;border:1px solid;">old div
</div>

<div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;border:1px solid;">old div
</div>

<div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;border:1px solid;">old div
</div>

<div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center;margin-top:15px; border:1px solid;">old div
</div>
```

Hint: `style="..."` and `onclick="rowAdd()"` are not a good practice, better add and stlye a class. And maybe read about `addEventListener`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of undefined
    at rowAdd at **Line A**
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick at **Line B**

Comment: The `+` button is now working in my example.

Comment: I am still getting the same result. What I am getting now in the DOM is this https://jsfiddle.net/79016wqm/

Comment: I have mentioned in the problem statement what I want to achieve.

Comment: You want to add the form ahead of every div? So 4 div get 4 forms? then you need a loop over the `getElementsByClassName ` results.

Comment: No. I want divs (4/5/6 or many. Depending on how much user is adding ) to be present inside the form.

Comment: Since it's closed, here goes my answer:
https://jsfiddle.net/r9masd4v/


insertAdjacentHTML() is not working as expected. The elements are beign created inside the first one.

Also, the function stacks elements in front of one another.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

You shouldn't have several elements with the same id on the same page.
Switch to class and chose the last element using a query selector.

Also, try to use javascript elements instead of writing HTML in javascript.

Comment: And what is wrong with the divs that I add, I gave them a border now that you can see them, each click adds one more div with 3 input fields. did you `run code snippet`?

Comment: Sorry, my comment was meant to be on the user's flash question. Although still makes more sense, to me, not using HTML in JS, but your sugestion on using eventListener is great